# Unexpectedly slow MYSQL query on newly indexed data

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I've got the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        CONCAT(COALESCE(location.google_id, ''),
                '-',
                COALESCE(locationData.resolution, ''),
                '-',
                COALESCE(locationData.time_slice, '')) AS google_id
    FROM
        LocationData AS locationData
            JOIN
        Location AS location ON location.id = locationData.location_id

    WHERE
        location.company_google_id = 5679037876797440
            AND location.google_id IN (4679055472328704, 6414382784315392, 5747093579759616)
            AND locationData.resolution = 8
            AND locationData.time_slice >= ((SELECT max(s.time_slice) FROM LocationData as s WHERE s.location_id = location.id ORDER BY s.time_slice ASC) - 255)
            AND location.active = TRUE
    ORDER BY location.google_id ASC , locationData.time_slice ASC
    LIMIT 0 , 101
```

I've got indices on all columns in the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses and I've added a compound index for (LocationData.time_slice, LocationData.location_id)

Running explain gives (which gave some challenges formatting here, so hopefully it shows up nicely):

```
   id | select_type        | table        | type  | possible_keys                              | key                |  key_len | ref                | rows | Extra
    1 | PRIMARY            | location     | range | PRIMARY,google_id_UNIQUE                   | google_id_UNIQUE   | 8        | NULL               |    3 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
    1 | PRIMARY            | locationData | ref   | max_time_slice_idx,max_time_slice_idx_desc | max_time_slice_idx | 5        | index2.location.id |  301 | Using where
    2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | s            | ref   | max_time_slice_idx,max_time_slice_idx_desc | max_time_slice_idx | 5        | index2.location.id |  301 | Using index
```

I know the dependent subquery is slow, and I'm open to suggestions for getting similar behavior, but I'm seeing this query take about 92 seconds to run, which is about 4 orders of magnitude different than test data I ran before adding the new compound index to production.

Is there index building that happens after the ALTER statement is run? Is there some way to check that the index is performing correctly?

Row counts for the two tables:

Production:

> Location: 6,814
>
> LocationData: 13,070,888

Test Data:

> Location: 626
>
> LocationData: 594,780

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` assuming InnoDB, or `key_buffer_size` if MyISAM?  My gut says you're undersized, and that 100% of the index isn't fitting in the buffer.

Comment: @dossy My setting is "innodb_buffer_pool_size 10049552384"

Comment: Okay, so that's roughly 10GB.  How large are the indexes?  `select table_name, round(sum(index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 2) from information_schema.tables where table_name in ('LOCATION', 'LOCATIONDATA') group by 1;`

Comment: @dossy Your script resulted in 1137.13. I assume that's MB?

Comment: Yeah, that's MB, so your indexes are 1.1 GB, so that should fit in 10 GB just fine.  Are your table rows _really_ long?  How many columns in each table?

Comment: @dossy Location has 7 columns 2 varchar(120) the rest int() LocationData has 5 columns 1 varchar(120) and 4 int().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181712/discussion-between-myles-and-dossy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion
you could avoid the subselect using an inner join

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT(COALESCE(location.google_id, ''),
            '-',
            COALESCE(locationData.resolution, ''),
            '-',
            COALESCE(locationData.time_slice, '')) AS google_id
FROM LocationData AS locationData
INNER JOIN Location AS location ON location.id = locationData.location_id
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT s.location_id, max(s.time_slice)  -255 my_max_time_slice
            FROM LocationData as s
            GROUP BY s.location_id
        ) t on t.location_id = Location.id

WHERE
    location.company_google_id = 5679037876797440
        AND location.google_id IN (4679055472328704, 6414382784315392, 5747093579759616)
        AND locationData.resolution = 8
        AND locationData.time_slice >= t.my_max_time_slice
        AND location.active = TRUE
ORDER BY location.google_id ASC , locationData.time_slice ASC
LIMIT 0 , 101
```

In this way you shoudl avoid the repeteation of the subquery for each id using just one query for buil the aggregated  result for the max_time_slice

hope this is useful

Answer (score 0):

(Adding onto the recommendation by @scaisEdge...)

```
WHERE   l.company_google_id = 5679037876797440
    AND l.google_id IN (4679055472328704, 6414382784315392, 5747093579759616)
    AND ld.resolution = 8
    AND ld.time_slice >= t.my_max_time_slice
    AND l.active = TRUE
ORDER BY l.google_id ASC , ld.time_slice ASC
```

Optimal indexes are, assuming the subquery needs to be run first.  (This is the case for older versions of MySQL.)

```
LocationData: (location_id, time_slice)  -- in this order, for the subquery
locationData: (time_slice, resolution, location_id)  -- for JOIN
```

If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `location`, there no extra index is needed there.

For newer versions, the subquery can be materialized and a suitable index can be built.  In this case, it would probably start with `location`:

```
location: (company_google_id, active,  -- in either order
           google_id)                  -- last
locationData:  (location_id, time_slice)  -- in this order (for subquery)
locationData:  (location_id, resolution   -- in either order (for JOIN)
                time_slice)               -- last
```

There is no way to optimize the `ORDER BY` since it hits two tables, nor any way to avoid a sort.

Sugges you add all of those indexes, then get `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` if you need to discuss it further.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` would also be handy.